# using generic type IProcess<T> requires 1 type argument - How to return generic interface?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have an interface as follow

```
public interface IProcess<T> where T : class
{
    void Process(string id);
}
```

I have a class which is having a dependency on other classes. So I am using constructor injection as follow

```
public class ProcessFactory: IProcessFactory
{
     public ProcessFactory(IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest> processSalaryRequest, 
                           IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest> processLeavesRequest)
        {
             _processSalaryRequest = processSalaryRequest;
             _processLeaveRequest = processLeavesRequest;
        }
     }

     public IProcess GetInstance(string type)//error comes here
     {
        Type atype;
        if (Enum.TryParse(type, out atype))
        {
            switch (atype)
            {
                case Type.Type1:
                    return _processSalaryRequest ;
                    break;
                case Type.Type2:
                    return _processLeaveRequest ;
                    break;
              }
        }
        return null;
     }
}
```

Here is the usage

```
 IProcess processRequest =  _ProcessFactory.GetInstance("Type1");
```

But i see below error,

> using generic type IProcess requires 1 type argument

How to fix the return type of 'GetInstance` method?

Comment: You'll have to pass the type argument expected by the interface. Where does the type name come from? Why not make the method itself generic? Another option is to ensure the type arguments share a common base class and mark it covariant, ie `IProcess<out T> where T : class`

Comment: Why is `IProcess<T>` generic if you aren't using the type parameter? Is there code you aren't showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We try to return `IProcess` that is a non-generic interface when the only interface that we can see in your code sample is generic - `IProcess<T>`. The compiler doesn't know how to convert `IProcess<T>` to `IProcess`.

One possible solution is to add a non-generic interface and make the generic interface inherit from it:

```
public interface IProcess
{
    void Process(string id);
}


public interface IProcess<T> : IProcess where T : class
{
}
```